# javascript help to move elements from one list to another

Tags: javascript

I have three lists (buckets) as below :

1. 'List of teams' (teamA, teamB, teamC)
2. 'List of members' (member1, member2 ...etc)
3. 'Selected Members' i.e an empty list which would be filled by items from the above two lists

And two buttons as below :

1. 'Select Members directly' -> this button moves one/more seleceted member(s) from the Member's list to the empty bucket on the R.H.S. I have implemented this and this is working.
2. 'Select Members by team' -> if one/more team(s) is selected in the Team's bucket , this button will move the associated team members from the Member's bucket to the empty bucket. I have half implemented this and stuck. So NEED HELP to complete this.

Rules :
1. Every team has some members associated with it. Member of one team might be a member of another team.

2. Once a member moves from the Member's bucket to the empty bucket (either by 'Select Members directly' or by 'Select Members by team'), the member would be removed from the Members bucket.
3. If one/more teams are selected and the 'Select Members by team' is pressed, the team would remain in the Team's bucket , only the associated members would be removed from the Member's bucket.
4. As two or more teams might have overlapping members, so if a member has already moved from the Member's bucket to the Empty bucket on R.H.S, then selection of a team would only move the member which is left in the Member's bucket .
5. Teams would not be removed from the Team's bucket, only associated members would be removed.

I am giving the code I have written so far below, please help me on the 'Select Members by team' button functionality as per my explanation above. I am using a JSON object to define the team and members relationship and it will always be like so. Kindly help. thanks.

```js
function appendapp(to, from) {
  var select1 = document.getElementById(to);
  var select2 = document.getElementById(from);
  var selectedArray = new Array();
  var i;
  var count = 0;
  if (select1.options.selectedIndex < 0)
    return false;
  for (i = 0; i < select1.options.length; i++) {
    if (select1.options[i].selected) {
      var val_select1 = select1.options[i].value;
      var text_select1 = select1.options[i].text;
      //alert('1st forloop text '+text_select1 + 'index '+i)
      select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option(text_select1, val_select1, false, false);
      selectedArray[count] = i - count;
      count++;
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < selectedArray.length; i++) {
    //alert('2nd forloop selectedArray '+selectedArray[i])
    select1.options[selectedArray[i]] = null;
  }
  var tmpAry = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < select2.options.length; i++) {
    tmpAry[i] = new Array();
    tmpAry[i][0] = select2.options[i].text;
    tmpAry[i][1] = select2.options[i].value;
    //alert('3rd forloop tmpAry-i-0 text '+tmpAry[i][0])
  }
  tmpAry.sort();
  //alert("before while select2optionslength ="+select2.options.length)
  while (select2.options.length > 0) {
    //alert('while loop')
    select2.options[0] = null;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tmpAry.length; i++) {
    var op = new Option(tmpAry[i][0], tmpAry[i][1]);
    //alert('last forloop '+op)
    select2.options[i] = op;
  }
  return;
}

function team2mem(sel, to, from) {

  var select1 = document.getElementById(sel);
  var select2 = document.getElementById(to);
  var select3 = document.getElementById(from);

  var selectedArray = new Array();
  var i;
  var count = 0;

  var maphash = {
    "teamA": ["member1", "member2", "member3"],
    "teamB": ["member4", "member5", "member6"],
    "teamC": ["member1", "member7", "member8"]
  };

  if (select1.options.selectedIndex < 0)
    return false;

  for (i = 0; i < select1.options.length; i++) {
    if (select1.options[i].selected) {
      var val_select1 = select1.options[i].value;
      var text_select1 = select1.options[i].text;
      //alert('1st forloop text '+text_select1 + ' index '+i);
      var apparr = maphash[text_select1];
      var apparrlen = apparr.length;
      //alert("apparray length = "+apparrlen);
      for (j = 0; j < apparrlen; j++) {
        var text_elem = maphash[text_select1][j];
        var var_elem = maphash[var_select1][j].value;
        //alert("new text ="+text_elem + " newvar ="+text_elem);
        select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option(text_elem, val_elem, false, false);
        //selectedArray[count] = i-count;    
        count++;
      }

    }
  }
  return;
}
```

```html
<div align="center"><font color="red"><b><span id="Error_App"></span></b></font>
</div>
<br>
<font size=3><b>List Of Teams</b></font>
<table border=0 width=100%>
  <tr>
    <td width=35%>
      <select multiple="multiple" id="teams" style="width:100%;" size="10">
        <option value=AA>teamA</option>
        <option value=BB>teamB</option>
        <option value=CC>teamC</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width=30% align="left">
      <input title='SelectTeamMem.' type="button" id="add" value="Select members by team ->" onclick="team2mem('teams', 'mems', 'bin')"></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width=10%></td>
    <td width=20% align="right">
      <td width=60% valign="bottom">
        <font size=2>Selected Members</font>
        <br>
        <select multiple="multiple" id="bin" style="width:100%;" size="10">
        </select>
      </td>
      <td width=10%></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div align="center"><font color="red"><b><span id="Error_App"></span></b></font>
</div>
<br>
<font size=3><b>List of Members</b></font>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width=35% valign="bottom">
      <select multiple="multiple" id="mems" style="width:100%;" size="10">
        <option value=16313>member1</option>
        <option value=16250>member2</option>
        <option value=15041>member3</option>
        <option value=15041>member4</option>
        <option value=15041>member5</option>
        <option value=15041>member6</option>
        <option value=15041>member7</option>
        <option value=15041>member8</option>
    </td>
    <td width=30% valign="top">
      <br>
      <br>
      <input title='SelectMembers' type="button" id="add" value="Select Members directly ->" onclick="appendapp('mems','bin')"></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: First, please [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), it is a light weight framework for working with "Models" and "Collections". 
For e.x. in your case you can have the "Members" as a model with the team name as an attribute. 
In the view you can handle click events and manage them easily.

You can find some tutorials here: http://backbonetutorials.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading about the Javascript Array methods on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Look specifically at map, reduce, and filter.

Also consider using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) as a helper library